# Can't post a message to Microsoft Teams via logic app in azure

Tags: json, azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app in azure that is as follows.
[image: Logic app in azure]

The parse JSON is - json(decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData']))

The output of the parseJSON is:

Body

```
  {
    "Message": "New message from logic app",
    "TeamID": "testNotificationsTeams",
    "ChannelID": "General"
  }
```

[image: Post message screen]
In the post message I have TeamID, ChannelID, and Message. They all get filled with the right info, but I still get an error:

```
  {
   "error": {
   "code": "BadRequest",
   "message": "teamGroupId needs to be a valid GUID.",
   "innerError": {
     "date": "2020-10-08T06:42:57",
     "request-id": "a0f985df-113e-48d5-8386-25c1752e7d05",
     "client-request-id": "a0f985df-113e-48d5-8386-25c1752e7d05"
 }
}
```

I can't understand why I am getting this error, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not sending the correct teamdID and ChannelID.